# All paths through this function will call itself

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

I created a `convenience init` for `UIColor` in below two ways:

1.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ red: CGFloat, _ green: CGFloat, _ blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

2.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(_ red: CGFloat, _ green: CGFloat, _ blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init(red/255, green/255, blue/255, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

For the second way I am getting a warning: "All paths through this function will call itself".
So I am unable to understand why this warning for second way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 2nd `init`, you're making a **recursive call** to the same `init(_:_:_:alpha:)`.

```
self.init(red/255, green/255, blue/255, alpha: alpha)
```

The above statement does not call the *designated initializer* of `UIColor`. It will call itself repeatedly.

Instead you must call `init(red:green:blue:alpha:)` like you did in the 1st case.